# How do I concatenate strings to generate fixed width output

Tags: c, concatenation

I have an array of structures, where each structure contains a first name and a last name, along with other information. I'm trying to print the array in tabular form, something like this

```
+---------------------------+--------+--------+
| Student Name              | Test 1 | Test 2 |
+---------------------------+--------+--------+
| Pousseur, Henri           |   95   |   92   |
| Boyer, Charles            |   90   |   97   |
+---------------------------+--------+--------+
```

However, my output looks like this

```
+---------------------------+--------+--------+
| Student Name              | Test 1 | Test 2 |
+---------------------------+--------+--------+
| Pousseur, Henri                  |   95   |   92   |
| Boyer, Charles                     |   90   |   97   |
+---------------------------+--------+--------+
```

My question is, how do I concatenate the last name to the first name (with a comma in between), and then print the whole thing as a fixed width string? So that my table lines up correctly.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NAME_LEN 25

typedef struct
{
    char fname[NAME_LEN+1];
    char lname[NAME_LEN+1];
    int score1;
    int score2;
} STUREC;

void printRecords(STUREC records[], int count)
{
    printf("+---------------------------+--------+--------+\n");
    printf("| Student Name              | Test 1 | Test 2 |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------+--------+--------+\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf ("| %-s, %-26s| %4d   | %4d   |\n", records[i].lname, records[i].fname, records[i].score1, records[i].score2 );

    printf("+---------------------------+--------+--------+\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    STUREC records[] = {
        { "Henri"  , "Pousseur", 95, 92 },
        { "Charles", "Boyer"   , 90, 97 }
    };

    printRecords(records, 2);
}
```

Comment: Does the code you have posted have any bearing on the question?

Comment: use `sprintf` or `snprintf`.

Comment: Please try to post a minimal example - be specific about the issue you are having and what you have tried, and post the LEAST amount of code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: well i just wanted to show the code... my issue is i can't get the records[count].fname to concatenate onto the end of records[count].lname... i tried using the code i posted in the in the begining, i tried using strcat(s1, s2);

Comment: when i try strcat(records[count].fname, records[count].lname); it compiles, but changes absolutely nothing.

Comment: @seanncurtis: How do you know `strcat()` didn't concatenate the strings? Could you post the code that convinced you it didn't?

Comment: @EOF : I believe the op is more concerned about alignment that concatenation. His explanation in the beginning obfuscated things a bit..

Comment: @EOF when i printf the string records[count].lname it only prints the lname string it read from the file, the lname string is not added to the end of it.

Comment: @sjsam with the little knowledge of c i do have, it seems concatenating would be the easiest thing. my issue is that i can't print my data in my chart with two diff name strings (lname and fname) that are variables... atleast i can't and keep them like "last, first" without a huge gap between the last name and the ",".

Comment: here is the code where i try to use strcat, and if you run it, you can see that when i print records[count].lname, it doesnt not have the first name (fname) string attached to the end of it, i updated the main question code to it...

Comment: Maybe because you're only calling `strcat` for the record after the last record, instead of for every record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `printf` returns the number of characters printed. So if you want to print the name within a fixed width, you can print the name, and then output spaces as needed to fill the width.

```
#define WIDTH 26

int count = printf( "%s, %s", records[i].lname, records[i].fname );
if ( count < WIDTH )
    printf( "%*s", WIDTH-count, "" );
```

In the format string `"%*s"`, the `*` tells printf that the width of the string will be passed as an argument. The `WIDTH-count` argument is the number of spaces that need to be printed, and `""` is just an empty string. So for example, if `count` is 16, then `WIDTH-count` is 10, so the `printf` is equivalent to

```
printf( "%10s", "" );
```

which will print 10 spaces.

Comment: woah, i've never seen this before... can you elaborate? not sure what everything (mainly towards the end is saying) and where does this go?

Comment: i think the real issue with this, is that i'm prinint all type of data into a 'created chart' if you will. not sure if i would be able to print like this into it.

Comment: @seanncurtis This code replaces the code that prints the name, where you have `printf ("| %-s, %-26s ...`.

Comment: The wildcard `*` here is what you should be concerned about. It is a mechanism the `printf` provides to make adjustments in string width.. Here the unfilled spaces that is `WIDTH-count` is filled with null characters..

Comment: im just getting a segment fault any time i try this.

Comment: i think i'd want to stick with concatenating the strings... because if i can get the fname string onto the end of the lname string making it one string, i can easily a efficiently manipulate the print statements because i'm experienced with printing a single string. would you by any chance be able to help me in this? like i said, when i added a strcat in my loop, it literally did nothing, in my print statement it only prints the lname without the fname added to it.

Comment: You need to take a step back, and learn how `printf` works, instead of going off on a tangent with concatenation. For example, `printf("hello "); printf("world\n");` does the same thing as `printf("hello world\n");`

Comment: i may be new to c, but i assure you not this new. haha. yes, that's how i attempted to insert the code you provided me, but it gave me a segment fault.

Comment: I have a feeling that the segfault came from the `strcat` that you added to the code.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int count = printf( "|%s, %s", records[i].lname, records[i].fname );
if ( count < NAME_LEN )
    printf( "%*s", NAME_LEN - count, "" );
        printf ("| %-7.6d| %4d   | %4d   | %4d   | %4d   | %4d   | %6.2f  |  %-2s   |\n", records[i].lname, records[i].id, records[i].score1,
                 records[i].score2, records[i].score3, records[i].score4, records[i].score5,
                  records[i].ave, records[i].grade);
    }     is how i attempted

Comment: ^^ woah that code turned out ugly looking on here, sorry. but no, i removed the strcat before inserting the provide code.

Comment: You forgot to remove the `records[i].lname`.

Comment: i removed it, and still a segment fault. i honestly don't see where anything would cause a segment fault, what i have/what you showed me seems perfectly fine.

Comment: it was a freaking tab issue... my second printf was tabbed over, causing the segment fault... wow

Comment: Ok, I don't really understand that, but if you got it working, great!

Comment: i have one more question... lets say i wanted to add 3 more blank spaces to the end of the name... how would i do that? or just in general change the blank spacing...

Comment: i dont understand either... i had the first printf; then the next directly under it, but a tab space before it. all i did was move it up next to it like print;print; and it worked

Comment: You could put three spaces at the start of the second `printf`, or just change the `WIDTH` define to 29.

Comment: and there it is... perfect. although i wish i understood how to operate the strcat function, this is a nice trick i've learned. thank you very much!

Comment: @user3386109 , i will be posting another question on here tonight concerning string compares. if you're up to it, you could jump on it with me! haha. not trying to throw out consecutive questions around, but i'm attempting to use these string functions in complicated (well, to me) codes when i only have examples and explanations of doing it in the most simplistic way. i know how to compare a string and a string. but i donot know how to compare a string from an array of structures, then re arrange the order of the whole chart in alphabetical order.

Comment: @seanncurtis I'll take a look, but questions usually get answered pretty quickly, so I expect you'll have an answer before I see the question :)

Comment: @user3386109 well i just posted it, and this isnt the first time you've came through and saved me in the clutch! keep up the good work haha.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an adpatation of @user3386109 answer.

Add

```
#define WIDTH 27 // You get a max width of 26
```

somewhere in the beginning of your program and a string

```
char fullname[WIDTH];
```

somewhere in the beginning of the main.

Then make changes like below :

```
printf("\n+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+\n");
    printf("| Student Name              |   ID   | Test 1 | Test 2 | Proj 1 | Proj 2 | Proj 3 | Average | Grade |\n");
    printf("+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+\n");

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
       int lname_len=strlen(records[i].lname);
       int fname_len=strlen(records[i].fname);
        snprintf(fullname,WIDTH,"%s,%s%*s", records[i].lname,records[i].fname,(WIDTH>(lname_len+fname_len)?(WIDTH-(lname_len+fname_len)):0),"");

        /* The above step concatenates - since you're very interested in it -
         * the sirname and the first name into a string fullname making sure
         * that the string is padded to 26 characters utmost.
         */

        printf ("| %s | %-7.6d| %4d   | %4d   | %4d   | %4d   | %4d   | %6.2f  |  %-2s   |\n", fullname, records[i].id, records[i].score1,
                 records[i].score2, records[i].score3, records[i].score4, records[i].score5,
                  records[i].ave, records[i].grade);
    }
    printf("+---------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+-------+\n");

    printf("\nHave A Terrible Day!\n\n");
```

Note the ternary expression :

```
(WIDTH>(lname_len+fname_len)?(WIDTH-(lname_len+fname_len)):0)
```

in `snprintf`. This will be evaluated to unused width, if any which we pad with emptry strings `""` or null characters.

If you didn't understand it please have a look [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html)